# Performance counter categories appear as numbers. How do I fix this?

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance-counters

I'm on a server (VM) and I have errors accessing performance counters (category does not exist). When I open Perfmon and try add a counter, I see this list of numbers in the list of categories. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempt to rebuild the Performance Counter Library by following the instructions here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956

Comment: All I had to do was copy the perfc009.dat file from another server. :D THANK YOU.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann no problems :)